# Importing vault/builtin/credential/aws adds testing flags to command-line app

Tags: go, command-line-interface, hashicorp-vault

I'm creating a quick and dirty Go app to pull application secrets from Vault, and authenticating using the Vault code itself. As part of this, I'm importing the aws credential module from `github.com/hashicorp/vault/builtin/credential/aws`. This is all working well.

However when running my app, I notice that the command line flags from the Go "testing" module are appearing in the flags.

This can be reproduced by compiling and running the following example script:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    _ "github.com/hashicorp/vault/builtin/credential/aws"
    // Note: this import is masked only to make this demo script compile.
    // In my actual code I need to use it, and it is not masked.
)

var myFlag string

func main() {
    flag.StringVar(
        &myFlag, "myFlag", "", "Test flag",
    )
    flag.Parse()
    flag.Usage()
}
```

The flags appear like so when calling the binary:

```
Usage of poc:
  -myFlag string
        Test flag
  -test.bench regexp
        run only benchmarks matching regexp
  -test.benchmem
        print memory allocations for benchmarks
  -test.benchtime d
        run each benchmark for duration d (default 1s)
  -test.blockprofile file
        write a goroutine blocking profile to file
  -test.blockprofilerate rate
        set blocking profile rate (see runtime.SetBlockProfileRate) (default 1)
  -test.count n
        run tests and benchmarks n times (default 1)
  [... more flags from the go testing module ...]
```

I'm a newbie to Go, so it's entirely possible I'm doing something I'm not supposed to here, but at first glance it seems reasonable to import this module for a command-line tool.

As far as I can see, nothing within the module uses the testing library (other than backend_test.go), so I'm a bit confused as to how these flags are appearing, especially as they don't appear in the Vault command line interface itself.

Is it possible to import and use Vault's credential/aws module without including these flags? Or somehow clear the testing flags before defining my own?

Comment: Just FYI, hashicorp likes to define test helpers in `testing.go` as opposed to `_test.go` files so that the helpers can then be imported and used by other packages. In the case of the `aws` package, some of its non testing files import the `framework` package which does have a `testing.go` file that imports the `testing` package from the std lib. So, just be ready, when using hashicorp libs, to have your flagspace polluted with the testing flags.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. Looks like using a separate flagspace is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because even though you use `_` to mask `github.com/hashicorp/vault/builtin/credential/aws`, the import auctually happened. And the package imported `testing`, which generate all these flags.

You can get rid of the `testing` flags by using a new FlagSet.

```
func main() {
    f:=flag.NewFlagSet("Your app name",flag.ExitOnError)
    f.StringVar(
        &myFlag, "myFlag", "", "Test flag",
    )
    f.Parse(os.Args)
    f.Usage()
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/O8ibPn77L46

Comment: Sorry, I perhaps wasn't clear, this script is to demonstrate the issue, and is not my actual code.I need to use the aws module, and it is correct that it is imported, however I don't want the flags from the testing module to be in my app.